# Modify a JSON file while preserving object key order

Tags: json, node.js, object

What is a good way to parse a JSON file in NodeJS, make minor modifications to it, then write it back to disk, without changing the order of any of the keys of any of the objects within it?

To address the usual concern "But JSON doesn't guarantee key order! What you're doing isn't JSON! You'll break the internet for everybody!":

- Humans often work on JSON configuration files. Even if the key order is of no significance to the program, they may have organised it in a certain way and don't want to see that move.
- JSON files are often committed into source control. Changing key order for no reason causes revision history spam.
- JSON files are often used for interoperability. Just because my program is pure and holy and standards-compliant doesn't mean that some other program it interoperates with is.

So: clearly this isn't sufficient:

```
var j = require('myfile.json');
...
fs.writeFileSync('myfile.json', JSON.stringify(j));
```

How can this be done, without writing a complete parser from the ground up?

Comment: it depends upon "minor modifications". Are you adding new keys or just modifying the values.

Comment: Modifying existing values, mostly. In my current specific case, I'm adding some keys at a lower level of the tree, but I don't care whether the order of the keys around those are preserved - but I do care whether the top level keys are preserved.

Comment: Have you tested to make sure that in the real world it does not already preserved the order? Even if it does preserve the order, what about spacing?

Comment: It's really hard to test for something like that when a library specifically does not guarantee the behaviour. Let's say it works for one given file on my machine...now what? Test on another machine? Different version of NodeJS? Bigger file? At what point can I trust that this undocumented behaviour is reliable? What about the next version of NodeJS? etc.